# setspace and quoting environment result in superfluous empty line

Tags: line-spacing, incompatibility, quoting, setspace

I was trying to set up the `quoting` environment by the package of the same name, which included single line spacing for block quotes as opposed to one and a half line spacing for normal text. The spacing seemed weird to me, so I boiled it down to the following MWE, which clearly shows off the extra line when applying `singlespacing` to `quoting`, even though nothing ought to happen because single line spacing is the standard.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[66]

\begin{quoting}
\lipsum*[66]
\end{quoting}

\lipsum*[66]

\newpage

\quotingsetup{font=singlespacing}

\lipsum*[66]

\begin{quoting}
\lipsum*[66]
\end{quoting}

\lipsum*[66]
\end{document}
```

Notes: The order in which `setspace` and `quoting` are loaded does not seem to matter. I also made sure `lipsum`'s paragraph breaks don't disturb us by using `\lipsum*`, which doesn't insert `\par`s.

[image: output]

Is this expected behavior, can I patch it, is it a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the user guide to the `quoting` package, the following is said about using the `font=...` argument in a `\quotingsetup{font=...}` command:

> **font** The font used for typesetting the contents of a quoting environment. Permitted
>   values are the names (without preceding backslash) of LATEX's fontswitching/
>   formatting commands; e. g, use font=itshape to typeset quotes
>   in italics. (By default, quoting uses the font/formatting of the surrounding
>   text.) To specify several font properties, use a comma-separated list of
>   font/formatting names, e.g., font={itshape,raggedright} (note the surrounding
>   braces).

What this comes down to, then, is that the package doesn't think (rightly or wrongly...) that `singlespacing` is a valid *font* switching or formatting instruction and ends up throwing in an extra blank line before (but interestingly not after) the quoted material.

Elsewhere in the user guide, there's also a comment that

> The options **font** and **font+** [of the `\quotingsetup` command] do not accept values which itself take an argument. In such cases you must resort to redefining the command `\quotingfont`.

Specifically, to change the line spacing in a `quoting` environment [to singlespacing, say], there's a suggestion to use the instruction

```
\renewcommand*{\quotingfont}{\setstretch{1.0}}
```

(with the `setspace` package loaded, naturally).

Indeed, with this modification, your MWE works as one would expect it to.

Comment: The question is: Why does `font` not accept values that take an argument, and does it accept macros that stand for a macro taking an argument? I would assume the answer to the latter question is yes. `\singlespacing` is defined as follows: `\newcommand{\singlespacing}{\setstretch{\setspace@singlespace}\vskip \baselineskip}`. If I change that and get rid of `\vskip \baselineskip`, my MWE also behaves as expected. The line containing these two commands is commented `% Correction for coming into singlespace`. It seems necessary for normal paragraphs, but I'll have to test that.

Comment: @doncherry - I must confess that I was a bit unsure about the precise meaning of the claim in the second quoted passage, or why it would apply to the `\singlespacing` macro, as it doesn't actually take an argument. Anyway, I think you've found, by unearthing the actual definition of the `\singlespacing` command, that it's the presence of `\vskip \baselineskip` rather than the command (not) taking an argument that's responsible for the extra amount of vertical whitespace. Safer to just type `\setstretch{1.0}` -- or to use Harish's solution based on `etoolbox`...

Answer (score 6):

Adding to **Mico**'s excellent answer, the problem can be solved by using `etoolbox` with its `\AtBeginEnvironment` macro:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\lipsum*[66]

\begin{quoting}
\lipsum*[66]
\end{quoting}

\lipsum*[66]

\newpage

\AtBeginEnvironment{quoting}{\singlespacing}
%\quotingsetup{font=singlespacing}

\lipsum*[66]

\begin{quoting}
\lipsum*[66]
\end{quoting}

\lipsum*[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Mico and Harish Kumar have already suggested ways to remove the extra blank line. I'll add that this "feature" of the `setspace` package isn't limited to `quoting`, but affects also the LaTeX standard environments `quote` and `quotation`: Whenever you issue `\singlespacing` *inside* the environment, `setspace` adds an extra blank line:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[66]

\singlespacing

\begin{quotation}
\lipsum*[66]
\end{quotation}

\lipsum*[66]

\newpage

\lipsum*[66]

\begin{quotation}
\singlespacing

\lipsum*[66]
\end{quotation}

\lipsum*[66]
\end{document}
```

Comment: So this addresses the "why" part of the question, I assume? It doesn't seem like `quoting` is based on `quote` or `quotation` though, or is it? I.e., is there any particular reason for this behavior? Is there any case in which it is needed for a desired result?

Comment: @doncherry It seems to be a bad interaction between `setspace` and the `list` environment on which `quoting` & friends are based.

Comment: Could this bad interaction be fixed on the side of one of these packages? I don't entirely understand how `setspace` works, but it seems the "mistake" is on that side, if it's problematic with the `list` environment in general?